# Cannot use Mean Squared Logarithmic Error (negative predicted values) though normalized data and predictions > -1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to implement a simple Sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression model and evaluate its performance through MSLE:
MSLE is based on SLE = (log(prediction + 1) - log(actual + 1))^2

I have something like 15 features, which all are normalized or standardized, all positive.
Though when I try to do a cross validation on my training data:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

lin_reg = LinearRegression()

linreg_scores = cross_val_score(lin_reg, X_train, y_train, cv = 10, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_log_error')
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: Mean Squared Logarithmic Error cannot be used when targets contain negative values.

So I checked by hand doing a manual cross validation with sklearn.model_selection.KFold, in order to print the predicted values for each fold...

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error
from sklearn.base import clone

kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=5)
lin_reg = LinearRegression()

split_count = 0
for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X_train, y_train):
    split_count += 1
    clone_reg = clone(lin_reg)
    X_tr = X_train.loc[train_index, :]
    X_val = X_train.loc[val_index, :]
    y_tr = y_train.loc[train_index]
    y_val = y_train.loc[val_index]
    clone_reg.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
    pred = clone_reg.predict(X_val)
    if any(pred<0):
        print(split_count)
        print(pred[pred<0])
```

The thing is, I do get negative predicted values, but they are all between [-1, 0]:

```
1
[-0.08642619]
3
[-0.2426673]
5
[-0.51744243]
```

So according to the MSLE formula, (y_predict + 1) should be positive, thus ln(y_predict + 1) should be mathematically correct.

Is there something that I am missing here?

Thanks a lot for your help, I'll obviously provide any additional info if needed!

Comment: You say "MSLE is based on SLE = (log(prediction + 1) - log(actual + 1))^2" but where does 1 come from?  It doesn't seem to indicate that in the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_log_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_log_error  why not shift the target by one before you apply `cross_val_score()`.

Comment: Well scikit-learn doesn't indicate which formula they base their MSLE on, but honestly I just took it for granted since it's what comes out first when googling 'mean squared logarithmic error formula'
But you get a point, I'll try to do everything manually (cross validation + defining my own MSLE function) in order to see if things work that way

Comment: you can define your own MSLE function and pass it to `cross_val_score()`.

Comment: I just did create my own MSLE function and instantiated a scorer object with make_scorer, in order to pass it as an argument in cross_val_score(). Though I still get this message: 'invalid value encountered in log'.

Also, I just checked in scikit-learn documentation and they do use log(y + 1): see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) at paragraph 3.3.4.5.

Comment: Also, when searching for this metrics code, I found out that there is a condition to be verified for it to run smoothly: y_true > 0 and y_pred > 0.

Though I do not get why would (y_true > -1 and y_pred > -1) not be sufficient for the metrics to be calculated...

Comment: I looked at the source code and saw the same thing as you pointed out (I posted issue https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18587).